# How to find internal hard drive when booting from USB?

Tags: 12.10, mount, live-usb

Trying to rescue a friend's computer. Put Ubuntu 12.10 on a Flash drive, changed the boot order, and fired it up; no problem. But now that I'm in, I can't seem to find the internal drive!

Any thoughts? I ran `sudo fdisk -l` in the Terminal and got this:

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.6 GB, 15610576896 bytes

```
119 heads, 55 sectors/track, 4658 cylinders, total 30489408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot     Start         End      Blocks  Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *       8064    30489407    15240672   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

99% sure that's the flash drive; it's 16GB. If that is the internal drive, I'm just not sure how to mount it. When I tried to `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/point` it told me `mount: only root can do that`.

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo` at the beginning of the command?

Comment: @Lucio - oh man, was hoping that wasn't my problem :P I re-ran it with `sudo` and didn't get an error, but I went into `mnt/point` and looked at the contents and it really looks like my flash drive's contents. It has wubi.exe and stuff in it; it's identical to the contents of the `cdrom` folder. So I can pretty confidently say it's not my internal hard drive.

Comment: Ehh, you usually have to mount the internal drive when booting from a liveUSB.  If you open up the file manager do you see any extra drives?

Comment: Is really that **all** the output of the command? To compare, [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5624119/) is my output.

Comment: @Lucio - edited to add the output above the drive list.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, you were right. It seems to be the flash drive. What is the size (in gigabytes) of the *hard-drive*?

Comment: @Seth, I opened up System Monitor and went to File Systems...I see `/dev/sdb1` mounted twice and `/dev/loop0`...I don't think any of those are the internal drive.

Comment: @Brendan Does the *file manager* show anything?  The hard drive probably isn't mounted.

Comment: @Lucio - hmm...not sure. I'm guessing 160 or 250GB based on my friend's guess and some sites that show specs.

Comment: @Seth, sorry my Ubuntu lingo isn't all there :/ File Manager = Home Folder? I went into that and didn't see anything; only the "Computer" and "Network" headers on the left. http://imgur.com/0juvgfH

Comment: Nothing like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ry3eJ.png)?

Comment: @Seth nope. :( Hoping this isn't bad news for the hard drive...is it possible that when I switched the boot order I did something to keep it from showing at all?

Comment: @Brendan No, but it could mean the hard drive has already died.  This would depend on what happened to your friends computer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments for more info on this question, but I think the only real problem was that the hard drive is damaged. Reboots and prayer were the only thing making it go...we'd reboot, see it mounted, copy some stuff, then it would presumable hit a bad sector, freeze/go gray, and disappear until we rebooted again.

Comment: But did you mounted/used/see the HDD in any time or not?

Comment: Yeah, it appeared in the File Manager as I would have expected upon rebooting. We were able to get some of the files off, but then we'd hit a bad sector and then the drive would either unmount, stop showing files, or just stop copying files.

Answer (score 1):

The few times I've done that sort of thing, I used Puppy linux, (newer version is called Slacko), and previous to that Knoppix and AntiX, which were supposed to be better at "finding" hard drives.  Best, and easiest way to make a USB, in my opinion,is to use LinuxLive. If the drive is readable, should show up on the desktop in the lower left corner, and you can just click on it.  Hope this helps.