# Access internal drive when booting from a USB key

Tags: mount, live-usb, disk

I have a Dell XPS 13 with a 256GB internal drive, partitioned to dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. After a firmware update, the laptop will no longer boot into Ubuntu, but it will boot into Windows, so the internal drive is not damaged.

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 installed on an 8GB SanDisk USB key, and can boot the laptop into Ubuntu with that.

Using the information at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269331/how-to-find-internal-hard-drive-when-booting-from-usb), I ran `sudo fdisk 1`, and I see 16 entries for 64MiB volumes, in this format:

```
Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

These entries are named from /dev/ram0 to /dev/ram15, and are followed by this:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1459982336 bytes, 2851528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8002732032 bytes, 15630336 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0030553a

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 15630335 15628288  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Although this represents slightly more than 8 GB in total, none of these entries appear to refer to any of the partitions on the internal drive.

I'm still at the shallow end when it comes to understanding all the power of the command line interface, so I would appreciate simple explanations.

What do I need to do to access the internal drive?

---

EDIT. This is what the  `/boot` directory looks like:

```
# tree /boot
/boot
├── abi-4.4.0-31-generic
├── config-4.4.0-31-generic
├── efi
│   └── EFI
│       └── ubuntu
│           ├── fw
│           └── fwupx64.efi
├── grub
│   ├── gfxblacklist.txt
│   ├── grubenv
│   └── unicode.pf2
├── memtest86+.bin
├── memtest86+.elf
├── memtest86+_multiboot.bin
└── System.map-4.4.0-31-generic
```

Comment: is the USB key booting in EFI mode?

Comment: for fixing the boot -- did you open the firmware settings (it's not called BIOS for EFI systems) and see if you can select the OS to boot. The update probably set it to Windows.

Comment: @ravery Thank you for your input. How do I find out if it was booting in EFI mode? I've asked a [separate question](https://askubuntu.com/q/975935/426741) about fixing the boot. Perhaps you could tell me there how to "open the firmware settings".

Comment: easiest way is to open the file manager and look for the directory /boot/efi.

Comment: this is for the LiveCD yes?, can you post the tree for the efi partition on the  HDD?

Comment: @ravery - That's exactly my problem. If I could post the tree for any part of the laptop's ssd, that would mean that I had access to it. From the version of Ubuntu running an a LiveUSB key. where should I look to find the mount point for the internal drive?

Comment: All the partitions should be listed on the left side of your file manager. If they aren't try running disks or gparted and look for unmounted partitions.

Comment: @OrganicMarble No partitions were listed, and disks and gparted could only see the LiveUSB disk. As I explain in my answer below, a system scan found a partition error and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a system scan fixed (this part of) the problem.

I pressed F12 while the computer was rebooting. An 8-bit menu appeared and I chose the System Scan. This ran for about 15 minutes and detected a problem in the partition table. At the end of the scan, it fixed the problem, and now I can see four disks in the Unity Launcher on the left of the screen.

Now, when I run `disks` or `gparted` or execute `sudo fdisk -l`, I also have access to the 256 GB ssd disk.

Comment: Good news! sounds like your partition table was damaged. I'm glad it was able to be fixed.